# How to installer calendar module for Python 3.4 and above?

Tags: python, datetime, calendar, python-3.4

How to installer calendar module for Python 3.4 and above?

I used cmd with command  ** pip install calendar** but this command return me this error:

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement calendar (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for calendar

Anyone can share me idea? because I going to do this tutprial 
 https://pymotw.com/3/calendar/

Comment: You don't install this module at all. It's part of the standard lib. Do you get an error when you try `import calendar`?

Comment: no error actually

Comment: but it return me no calendar module

Comment: What does that mean? Can you post some code that shows the problem?

Comment: Sorry, i get my error already because due to the typo calendar become calender, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be Typing error. You don't have to install calendar module.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to import 'calendar package'. It is a default package that automatically comes with python.

Write the following code in the python shell:

```
import calendar  
cal2=calendar.month(2020,11)
print(cal2)
```

Output:

```
November 2020
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
                   1
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20 21 22
23 24 25 26 27 28 29
30
```

**Note : I have checked it and implemented it on my pc. You will get the exact same output as mentioned above.**

Answer (score -1):

Remember that in Python 2.x, you need parenthesis just after the word 'print', like this: **print(calendar.monthrange(now.year, now.month)[1])**

Comment: This is actually the other way around. The syntax that you posted is for Python3.x